# Series convergences with different terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence

Consider a serie $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^Nu_n$ with $u_n$ taking values either in a converging serie $T=\sum_{n=1}^Nt_n$, that is $u_n=t_n$ for some $n$ or taking the value $u_n=0$ for some other $n$.

I belief that the serie $S_N$ converges as well. Both term values converge to $0$ and if you take the full serie $T$ by changing the term with $0$, it should converge as well.

Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Next time, please, present your own efforts, thoughts, attempts to solve your problem.

Comment: $x_n\to0$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for $\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n$ to converge.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correct.

For example, if you take $t_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, then the series $$T=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots$$ converges, but if you take $$u_n=\begin{cases}t_n & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
then the series $S_n$ diverges.

---

What you need is absolute convergence. If $T$ is absolutely convergent, then it is easy to show that $S$ is, as well.

In fact, you can even show a stronger result, i.e.

> A series $T$ is absolutely convergent **if and only if** any series, constructed from $T$ by setting some of its elements to $0$, is convergent.

Comment: @gerfatrav No, in that case, $T$ is absolutely convergent, and $S_n$ will also be convergent.

Comment: Thank you for your help.